# Gruntfile.js uglify all files

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to create a Grunt task to uglify all files in a src folder and move them to a parent folder.

However when i try '*.js', the uglified js file in the parent folder is being created as '*.js'

```
    uglify: {
      my_target: {
        files: {
          'js/*.js': ['js/src/*.js']
        }
      }
    }
```

How can this be done so e.g. js/src/app.js converts to js/app.js. Mind that i don't want to specify each js file in my configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [building the files object dynamically](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically) in the grunt docs:

```
uglify: {
  my_target: {
    expand: true,
    flatten: true,
    cwd: 'js/',
    src: 'src/*.js',
    dest: 'js/',
  }
}
```